# Access a local variable from one method a different method on a form

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very simple form that produces a Datagridview with 4 columns.  No problem generating the form.  Only the last column can be edited.  After editing, I want to hit the OK button and join elements of the list in the last column into a string.  How do I make that list (current) available inside the the OK button object sender.  Sorry for my poor grammar.  I'm an obvious newbie.  Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Avisynth_Script
{
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string current_values = null;

    private void Load_Tweaker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] deshake_parts = EntryPoint.deshakeSettings.Split(',');
        List<String> settings = new List<string>(deshake_parts);
        string[] default_values = EntryPoint.deshakeDefaultValues.Split(',');
        List<String> defaults = new List<string>(default_values);
        string[] current_settings = current_values.Split('|');
        //current_settings[0] = current_settings[0].Substring(1);
        //current_settings[66] = current_settings[66].Substring(0, 6);
        List<String> current = new List<string>(current_settings);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i=0; i < settings.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i+1 ,settings[i], defaults[i], current[i]);
        }            
    }      

    private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EntryPoint.deshaker_param = string.Join('|', current.ToArray());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unbound `DataGridView` with four columns and want to concatenate the values in the fourth column separated by a "|" in the `OK_button_Click` method.

You could use a foreach loop to iterate each row in the `DataGridView`'s row collection and pull the value from the fourth column (index=3) to achieve this, or you could use a Linq query to perform the iteration.

Here is a Linq solution.

```
private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EntryPoint.deshaker_param = string.Join("|", dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => (!row.IsNewRow)).Select(row =>((row.Cells[3].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString())));
}
```

Comment: Works, but I did want to keep entries that are blank.  I tried to remove the condition with this code.  updated_values= string.Join("|", dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where((row) => (!row.IsNewRow)) .Select((row) => (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString())));  However, if cells are blank I get an exception.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: @WayneLWaag,  I updated the answer to remove null filtering.

Comment: Works except if the first or last row is blank.  By the way, it is bounded.  There are always 67 rows.

Comment: @WayneLWaag, your post shows adding rows directly to the `DataGridView.Rows` collection hence it is unbound.  A bound `DataGridView` has its `DataSource` property set.  Have you changed the basis of the question?  If, so please update you question to show the binding.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too difficult to move `current` to be a field-level variable, but that isn't the best option. Now that C# has lambdas in the language, you can basically inline the event handler and remove the `OK_button_Click` method entirely. This kind of encapsulation is a more robust approach than just making your variables have a higher level of access.

Using a field is like saying that someone in particular needs to write to a file on your computer so you'll just make that file available for everyone to access. You wouldn't do that with your files on your computer so you shouldn't do that in your code.

Inside a lambda you can access the method's local variables. You code can look like this:

```
    List<String> current = new List<string>(current_settings);

    OK_button.Click += (s, e2) =>
    {
        EntryPoint.deshaker_param = string.Join("|", current.ToArray());
    };
```

If you only ever call `Load_Tweaker` once then your code can be very simple:

```
private void Load_Tweaker(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] deshake_parts = EntryPoint.deshakeSettings.Split(',');
    List<String> settings = new List<string>(deshake_parts);
    string[] default_values = EntryPoint.deshakeDefaultValues.Split(',');
    List<String> defaults = new List<string>(default_values);
    string[] current_settings = current_values.Split('|');
    //current_settings[0] = current_settings[0].Substring(1);
    //current_settings[66] = current_settings[66].Substring(0, 6);
    List<String> current = new List<string>(current_settings);

    OK_button.Click += (s, e2) =>
    {
        EntryPoint.deshaker_param = string.Join("|", current.ToArray());
    };

    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, settings[i], defaults[i], current[i]);
    }
}
```

However, if you call `Load_Tweaker` more than once you need to manage the addition and removal of the handler for each call. It's a little more complicated, but not too bad.

```
private EventHandler okButtonClick = null;

private void Load_Tweaker(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] deshake_parts = EntryPoint.deshakeSettings.Split(',');
    List<String> settings = new List<string>(deshake_parts);
    string[] default_values = EntryPoint.deshakeDefaultValues.Split(',');
    List<String> defaults = new List<string>(default_values);
    string[] current_settings = current_values.Split('|');
    //current_settings[0] = current_settings[0].Substring(1);
    //current_settings[66] = current_settings[66].Substring(0, 6);
    List<String> current = new List<string>(current_settings);

    if (okButtonClick != null)
    {
        OK_button.Click -= okButtonClick;
    }

    okButtonClick = (s, e2) =>
    {
        EntryPoint.deshaker_param = string.Join("|", current.ToArray());
    };

    OK_button.Click += okButtonClick;

    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, settings[i], defaults[i], current[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the simple version.  Compiled OK, but it didn't work.  Changes made to the rows in "current" were not included when joined. The string remained the same.  How would you make current a "field level variable"?

Comment: @WayneLWaag - put a break-point on the `String.Join` and see if the code runs. That would be my first port-of-call. Otherwise just define `private List<string> current = null;` at the same point where `private EventHandler okButtonClick = null;` is and remove `List<string>` where you currently define current. But doing that is a backward move.